# D3 - Create a chart with 3 fixed y-axis ticks

Tags: d3.js, charts, yaxis

I have a D3 chart but only want to show 3 ticks for the y-axis.

Depending on the data, I sometimes get 3, 4 or 5 ticks which makes it difficult for me to style with CSS.

Here is the full code:

```
    // Create a new d3
    var chart = d3.select('#analytics-chart').append('div').attr('class', 'chart');
    chart.append('div').attr('class', 'y-axis');
    chart.append('div').attr('class', 'bars-and-x-axis');

    var barMargin = '0 2px',
        min = 0,
        max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return parseInt(d.value, 10);
        });

    var bars = d3.selectAll('.bars-and-x-axis').append('div').attr('class', 'bars'),
        xaxis = d3.selectAll('.bars-and-x-axis').append('div').attr('class', 'x-axis'),
        yaxis = d3.selectAll('.y-axis'),
        xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, data.length]),
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range(0, 100).domain([min, max]),
        barWrapper = bars.selectAll()
            .data(data.map(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            }))
            .enter()
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', function(d, i) {
                if (d == 0) {
                    return 'chart-data-wrapper empty';
                } else {
                    return 'chart-data-wrapper';
                }
            }).style('margin', barMargin);

    var bar = barWrapper.append('div').attr('class', 'chart-data-bar')
        .style('height', function(d) {
            return Math.ceil((d - min) / (max - min) * 100) + 'px';
        })
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'tooltip')
        .attr('style', function(d, i) {
            return 'left: ' + Math.ceil(i / data.length * 100) + '%; transform: translateX(-' + Math.ceil(i / data.length * 100) + '%); ';  
        })
        .append('p')
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return data[i].date;
        })
        .append('p')
        .attr('class', 'data')
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return data[i].content;
        });

    xaxis.selectAll()
        .data(xScale.ticks(12))
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'x-axis-mark');

    yaxis.selectAll()
        .data(yScale.ticks(3))
        .enter()
        .insert('small', ':first-child')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .text(function(d, i) {
            if (d > 999) {
                d = d / 1000 + 'k';
            } 
            return d;
        });

    var tick = d3.selectAll('.x-axis-mark')
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', function(d, i) {
            if (i % 3 == 1) {
                return 'x-axis-tick-with-label';
            } else {
                return 'x-axis-tick';
            }
        });

    var label = d3.selectAll('.x-axis-mark')
        .append('small')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .text(function(d, i) {
        var format = d3.time.format('%b');
            return data[i].xlabel;
        })
        .attr('class', function(d, i) {
            if (i % 3 != 1) {
                d3.select(this).remove();
            }
        });
```

Edit - I've added the full code and attached an image of the working example below:

[image: working example]

Comment: Is this your actual code?  You have a typo on your `.range` call and I've never seen anyone do a `yaxis.selectAll().data`..., usually with d3 v3, it's usually `var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale); svg.append("g").call(yAxis);`  Can you provide a complete example of what you are doing?  It's like you are creating the axis and then using data-binding to change it afterward.

Comment: On top of the above comment, `selectAll` is **never** a getter, and `small` is not a valid element. This code cannot possibly show **any** tick...

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the chart. I'm not using SVG's. `<small>` is a valid HTML element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

Comment: I know that. However, without seeing the relevant code, almost everybody would assume that you were creating an SVG. And, again, `selectAll` is **never** a getter.

Comment: Added the full code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replace `yScale.ticks(3)` in `.data(yScale.ticks(3))` with my own math function that returns an array of values to create the tick values.

Comment: Example would be nice.
```js
yScale.ticks(function(){return [10,20,30,40]})
```